# Craft 2 - Referencing Twig Variables in Javascript - Variables Do Not Exist

Tags: templating, error-message, craft2, javascript

I'm working with a template in Craft 2, and in referencing Twig variables in the Javascript, they are not recognized when the page is previewed.  I get a `Template Error - Variable x does not exist`

Initially, I constructed the Javascript function by referencing the Twig variables defined earlier in the template like this (below).  I got the error message that the Twig variable referenced here (`myText`) does not exist:

```
{%set myText=entry.body.getPage(1)|e('html')%}
{% set myJs %}
function myFunction(btn) 
{
    var FullText='{{myText}}';
}
{% endset %}
{% includeJs myJs %}
```

When I got the template error, I changed it to this (below), which gave the error that the variable reference here (`entry`) does not exist.:

```
{% set myJs %}
function myFunction(btn) 
{
    var myText='{{entry.body.getPage(1)|e('html')}}';
}
{% endset %}
{% includeJs myJs %}
```

Does this have to do with the positioning of the Javascript in the Template's code, or could it have to do with the Twig variables somehow?
Thanks for any leads.

Comment: I guess this might be a problem with `entry.body.getPage(1)|e('html')`. Have you tried to set mytext to something simple like "Hello World"? And could you edit `Template Error - Variable x does not exist` and add the actual variable name that does not exist? This would make it easier to tell what the error is.

Comment: don't know if that's the issue but i think you're missing an `{% endset %}` tag?

Comment: @Seb Thanks for the catch.  I corrected the example to reflect my code, which does have the `{%endset%}` tag.  It is giving the error message, even though the` {%endset%}` is there.

@Max I've included the error above.  Thanks

When I put 'hello world', it did work, but stopped working when I put the Twig there.